# When annotating an application as Eureka server, what is the need to specify its not a client

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka

Out of curiosity throwing this question. If the Springboot application is annotated with 
@EnableEurekaServer, what is the need for specifying the below properties in application.properties file.

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false

eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

Should Eureka be intelligent enough to understand this is a server and not client.

Answer (score 1):

`@EnableEurekaServer` - we use this annotation to convert our service into a Eureka Registry Server.
By default, Eureka registry also tries to register itself, so you need to disable the Eureka feature for registering the own instance by setting below property.

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
```

If `eureka.client.fetchRegistry` is true, the client fetches the Eureka server registry at startup and caches it locally.
[Refer this for more details-](https://blog.asarkar.org/technical/netflix-eureka/)

Comment: But my question is since we have already annotated the application as EurekaServer, why should we add those 2 properties. Why cant Spring assign internally false to the property eureka.client.register-with-eureka and eureka.client.fetch-registry